# Configure PCManFM to automount archives

Tags: linux, lxde, archive

**How can I setup PCManFM to mount an archive when double-clicking on it? Alternatively, how can I get this option in the right-click menu on an archive?**

(I used to have this on a machine running the Fedora LXDE spin, but when I clean installed Fedora 28 because of a failed hard drive, I seem to have lost it.)

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the `gvfs-archive` package.